# Regex Match with Square Bracket and letters

Tags: regex, azure-data-explorer, kql

How do you match regex containing letters and square bracket using kusto?

I am passing level as parametre and expect it to go until the level mentioned in the path. I have the following regex pattern to match but it doesn't include square bracket.

```
let level=4;
let string1= "abc/def/[id]/ghi"
let regex1=replace('level',tostring(level),'/?(([-a-z0-9]+/?){level})');
let result = extract(regex1,1,string1);
```

Output: abc/def

Expected output: abc/def/[id]/ghi 
(upto level 4, its discrading the characters once it finds square brackets

Comment: has any of the answers below helped? If so, please accept ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)'s why). Otherwise, please add a comment explaining what you're missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should escape the square brackets by putting a double-backslash before them, like this:

```
let string1 = "abc/def/[id]/ghi";
let result = extract("([-a-z0-9\\[\\]]*/){1,6}", 0, string1);
print result
```

Result:

```
abc/def/[id]/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could match either the characters in the character class or surround them by square brackets to match the opening one up with the closing one.

The quantifier `{0,0}` matches the first part, `{0,1}` matching a part starting with a `/` etc.

If the second part of the quantifier is greater than the maximum number of occurrences in the string like `{0,7}`, you will still get the highest level.

You can add an anchor to assert the start of the string to prevent partial matches.

```
^/?(?:[-a-z0-9]+|\[[-a-z0-9]+\])(?:/(?:[-a-z0-9]+|\[[-a-z0-9]+\])){0,2}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/npcHHS/1)

A broader match could be adding the square brackets to the character class, but that could possibly also match a single occurrence.

For example with a repetition of 2:

```
^/?[\]\[a-z0-9-]+(?:/[\]\[a-z0-9-]+){0,2}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w9jmBf/1)

In case the backslashes have to be double escaped:

```
^/?[\\]\\[a-z0-9-]+(?:/[\\]\\[a-z0-9-]+){0,2}
```

Comment: for some reason, this logic doesn't work in kusto. I update my post with the kusto functions I'm using. Also, if we pass level as 5 (grater than the number of slashes present in the path string, I would want it to return the highest possible level for the string, say if the string just has 3 paths, it should return until 3rd level even when the level value passed is 5)

Comment: @Swasti Can you try it like this `^/?[\]\[a-z0-9-]+(?:/[\]\[a-z0-9-]+){0,2}` or else with the doubled escaped backslashes `^/?[\\]\\[a-z0-9-]+(?:/[\\]\\[a-z0-9-]+){0,2}`